# HTML - document.referrer not read my full url

Tags: html, function, url, document, referrer

Please...I make a function that sends the email with the URL of the current page. But the property **document.referrer** **does not read the full url**.

Example: My url is www.mycolors.com/#!colorblue/clyd

But the e-mail looks like this: www.mycolors.com

Can anyone help me with an alternative?

Code:

```
function sendMail() {
    var x = document.referrer;
    var link = "mailto:" + escape(document.getElementById('myText').value)
             + "?cc=" + escape(document.getElementById('myText2').value)
             + "&subject=" + escape(document.getElementById('myText3').value)
    + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('myText4').value) + escape(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =x) + escape(document.getElementById('myText5').value)  
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The portion you are trying to reach is the hash part. The hash portion of URLs is never sent to the server, and it appears it is not stored in the javascript object for the `document.referrer`. There's no way to get it unless you control the referring page, and you pass along the hash fragment in the link.

Check out this for more information: [Uh-oh. AJAX-powered search kills keywords in referrers](http://razzed.com/2009/02/12/uh-oh-ajax-powered-search-kills-keywords-in-referrers/).

Possible duplicates:

- [How do you get location.hashtag from the referrer url - Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041148/how-do-you-get-location-hashtag-from-the-referrer-url-google-analytics).
- [Get Referrer URL including fragment identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846773/get-referrer-url-including-fragment-identifier).